# How to make on site macros?

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to have some macros on my site, example. [product]milk[/product], when its going to be showed the user i want it to get some data from "milk", image, product name, product description.

**EDIT**

I have 500+ [product] entries all of them have an image, product name, product desc. and if i write a recipe i want to be able to add an image of milk and eggs, by using [product]egg[/product] and [product]milk[/product], and it should be replaced with the data from above.

I thought about having it all maybe in an xml file or an array.

Comment: Have you tried anything by yourself? What is your approach? Maybe that will help us to understand your request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a general solution, which will allow you to replace [anyTagName]anyContent[/anyTagName], you can try the following code:

```
$regex = '/\\[(\\w+)\\](\\w+)\\[\\/\\1\\]/';
$content = 'A string with some [product]milk[/product] tags';

$parsedContent =  preg_replace_callback($regex,function ($matches) {
    return process_tags($matches[1],$matches[2]);
},$content);

function process_tags($tagName,$tagContent) {
    //What you return from this function will replace the [tagName]tagContent[/tagName] tags.
    if ($tagName == 'product') {
        //This is a product tag, return something based on $tagContent
    }
}
```

Comment: How would the regex look like if i would like to have a link inside "tagcontent" [product]www.youtube.com?v=something[/product]

Comment: @BluePanda It would be `$regex = '/\\[(\\w+)\\]([^[]+)\\[\\/\\1\\]/';`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple example. But you may check existing implementations of BBCODE parsers. THere might be useful examples.

```
function parse_product($input)
{
    if (is_array($input)) {
        //here you replace macros with desired content
        return '<span calss="my_product">'.$input[1].'</div>';
    }
}
return preg_replace_callback($'#\[product](\w+)[/product]#', 'parse_product', $input);
```

Answer (score 0):

In C a macro is a syntax replacement that the precompiler uses to both optimize the code
(avoid the unnecessary function jump for a short task) and make it easy to
write for the coder. The complier simply translates a pseudo code (the
macro) to actual code when the code is compiled to executable. Since PHP is
not precompiled, I don't see how this could be of any use. The php source
code should be precompiled in order to get the replaced... Macros just don't
have a purpouse in run-time compiled language like they do in precompiled
languages.

When I was working on modular system, where every module was a file with
object definition. I needed to make some global variables accessible in method of this
object (i.e. database connection object) in every module, but I wanted
to have a list of these variables only once in whole system (it would be
unpleasant to edit all modules if I decided to, for example, change name
of any of these variables).

Function is useless in this case, so I needed a macro.

I solved a problem this way:

```
// In initialisation part of code
define('MY_MACRO', 'global $database, $global_config,
$any_other_needed_variables;');

// In beginning of module object's method
eval (MY_MACRO);
```

But maybe there is much better way to do this

The difference is that macros are applied as text substitution before
parsing is carried out. This means that macros can carry out
substitutions on the code that would not in itself be a valid language
construct.

The classic example of misuse of this sort of technique in C is

```
#define BEGIN {
#define END }

then you can do silly things like:

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
BEGIN
printf("%d\n", i);
END
```

Used judiciously these sorts of techniques can open up all sorts of
possibilities.